# Laravel set timestamp timezone

Tags: laravel

Laravel has a `timestamp` that generates columns `created_at` and `updated_at`.

I want to ask what's the best way to set application timezone ? I want to set time zone for my application to **GMT+8**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change timezone value in `config/app.php` like :

```
'timezone'  => 'Asia/Kathmandu',
```

I've added `Asia/Kathmandu` in context of Nepal. You can add your Time Zone over there.

Note: Don't forget to clear configuration cache.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed! Haha, thank you for answering almost all of my questions here. :D

Comment: @JanArielSanJose Really ? Thanks ha ha Okay then please close the question by accepting it later.

Comment: If someone decides to use `$table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();` instead of Laravel's default timestamps, keep in mind that changing the timezone in app.php will be ignored and MySQL (or whatever db engine you use) timezone will be used instead.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: open file  `config/database.php.php`

Step 2: find 'mysql' section `'mysql' => [`

Step 3: add option here `'timezone'  => 'Asia/Baku',`

Step 4: clear-cache

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: open file `config/app.php`

Step 2: find keyword: `'timezone' => 'UTC'`

Step 3: Replace UTC to your timezone

Example: `'timezone' => 'Asia/Ho_Chi_Minh'`

Find your timezone at here https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ref_timezones.asp

Comment: Actually, get your timezone from the source: [the PHP documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.php)